# Showing that if $m \leq 2^n-1$, then the $m$-th Fermat number divides $2^{F_n}-2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fermat-numbers

The $m$-th Fermat number is defined by $F_m = 2^{2^m}+1$ (where $m\geq 0$ is an integer).

The condition that we must show is equivalent to $2^{F_n} = 2^{2^{2^n}+1} \equiv 2$ modulo $F_m$. This also shows that the order of $2$ modulo $F_m$ divides $F_n = 2^{2^n}+1$. However, what I find weird or unintuitive is how to use the inequality $m \leq 2^n-1$. Usually, when showing divisibilities, some inequalites turn out to be difficult obstables.

I believe this property of Fermat numbers may be helpful:
$$
F_m = \left( \prod_{i=0}^{m-1} F_i \right) + 2
$$
where $m \geq 1$ because it was also on the same exercise sheet. Still, I cannot relate this to the inequality assumption too.

Do you have any idea or helpful remarks to guide me through this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think as $2^{F_n}-2=2(2^{2^{2^n}}-1)=2(2-1)(2+1)(2^2+1)\dots(2^{2^{2^n-1}}+1)$ and $F_m$ for $m$ in the ranges is in the factorization.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn: It's probably pretty but I can't see right now why we can $2^{2^{2^n}}$ as $(2-1)(2+1)(2^2 +1) \dots (2^{2^{2^n}-1}+1)$. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that the Fermat number $F_j$ divides $F_k - 2$, where $0 \le j \lt k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433280/showing-that-the-fermat-number-f-j-divides-f-k-2-where-0-le-j-lt-k). This question just presents values somewhat differently from your question and is somewhat more general.

Comment: @ANTLearner: $(2-1)(2+1)=(2^2-1)$, $(2^2-1)(2^2+1)=2^4-1$, $(2^4-1)(2^4+1)=2^8-1$. Do you see it now?

Comment: @ANTLearner Note $2^{F_n} - 2 = 2(2^{2^{2^n}} + 1 - 1) - 2 = 2F_{2^n} - 4 = 2(F_{2^n} - 2)$. Thus, my proposed duplicate matches with $k = 2^n$ and $j = m$ giving $m \le 2^n - 1$. Also, with your property of Fermat numbers, using $m = 2^n$ gives $F_{2^n} - 2 = \left(\prod_{i=0}^{2^n-1}F_i\right)$, from which you can directly get your result as well.